# C# Optional Object Action MVC Parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Is it possible to specify an object as a parameter in MVC with default values in some way?

E.g.

```
    public virtual ViewResult Index(RequirementFilters requirementFilters)
```

I'd like to initialize the values of a couple of parameters on RequirementFilters?

At the moment I am doing

```
public virtual ViewResult Index(int status=1, bool required =false)
```

I wanted to create a Filter Object so I could re-use it but I can't figure out way of setting defaults for the object in the Action Parameters.

Thanks

Graeme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a custom ActionFilter attribute and create an instance of your Filter Object there. You can provide some properties through the custom attribute.

Here's an example:

```
public class DefaultQuerySettingsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
        public string ParameterName { get; set; }
        public Type SettingsType { get; set; }
        public int Rows { get; set; }
        public string SortColumn { get; set; }
        public string SortOrder { get; set; }
        public bool PagingEnabled { get; set; }

        public DefaultQuerySettingsAttribute()
        {
            this.ParameterName = "settings";

            var defaultSettings = new QuerySettings();
            this.Rows = defaultSettings.Rows;
            this.SortColumn = defaultSettings.SortColumn;
            this.SortOrder = defaultSettings.SortOrder;
            this.PagingEnabled = defaultSettings.PagingEnabled;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

            if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(this.ParameterName))
            {
                var querySettings = filterContext.ActionParameters[this.ParameterName] as QuerySettings;

              if (querySettings == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(querySettings.SortColumn))
                                        filterContext.ActionParameters[this.ParameterName] = this.GetQuerySettings();
            }
       }

        private QuerySettings GetQuerySettings()
        {
            var querySettings = (QuerySettings)Activator.CreateInstance(SettingsType ?? typeof(QuerySettings));
            querySettings.Rows = Rows;
            querySettings.SortColumn = SortColumn;
            querySettings.SortOrder = SortOrder;
            querySettings.PagingEnabled = PagingEnabled;

            return querySettings;
        }
   }
```

`ParameterName` is the name of the argument in the action method (`requirementFilters` in your case).
You can also specify actual type that will be instantiated by providing `SettingsType`.

Comment: Thanks will take a look at doing this I'm doing something a bit similar with an IModelEnricher that I use to populate select list and other ViewModel attributes to keep the controller thin

Answer (score 1):

Users sometimes prefer to see the defaults on screen, rather than allowing the system to hide the defaults internally.

A better way of having defaults will be to actually show the defaults on int UI, in the HTML by rendering it with together with the defaults. That way when someone posts the page, the defaults which you pre-rendered is also posted and binded to the model.

So try and see if you can render with defaults whatever for you are rendering and posted to the `Index` action.

Finally, if you can't do it that way, what is preventing you from initializing the properties with default values in the no-arg constructor while creating the object?

**EDIT**

Or you can use the C# language feature the null coalescent operator to implement defaults. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to read about it.

Comment: Yeah the defaults are shown. It's just the first visit to index I need to initialise the filters.

Comment: The 1st visit to index, you might try redirecting to Index with some parameters in the URL, if there are no params initially. I also edited the answer with another solution

Comment: I'm having problems with two index methods. I don't seem to be able to overload Index based on the parameters. I found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller%28VS.100%29.aspx and suggests I can't.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't need to change the defaults per action, you can set them in the default constructor of the Model.

Comment: Is it good practice to initialise values in the ViewModel constructor?

Comment: Values are always initialized, if the requirements are that they be initialized to a value different from the .Net defaults, that is what the constructor is for.